# If there is a regex match, append to list

Tags: python, excel, regex

I am trying to check a column of an Excel file for values in a given format and, if there is a match, append it to a list. Here is my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import re

#Open file and read column with PBSID.
PBSID = []
wb = load_workbook(filename="FILE_PATH", data_only=True)
sheet = wb.active
for col in sheet["E"]:
    if re.search("\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{5}", str(col)):
        PBSID.append(col.value)

print(PBSID)
```

Column E of the Excel file contains IDs like 431-00456 that I would like to append to the list named PBSID.

**Expected result**: PBSID list to be populated with ID in regex mask XXX-XXXXX.

**Actual result**: Output is an empty list ("[]").

Am I missing something? (I know there are more elegant ways of doing this but I am relatively new to Python and very open to critism).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, I think the for loop should be written as:

```
for row in sheet["E"]:
```

As I'm guessing that sheet["E"] is simply referring to the column 'E' already.

Without seeing exact data that's in a cell, I think what's happening here is that python is interpreting your call to str() as follows:
[image]

It's performing a maths operation (in my example) '256 - 23690' before giving you the string of the answer, which is '-23434', and then looking for your regular expression in '-23434' for which it won't find any match (hence no results). Make sure the string is interpreted as a *raw* string.

You also appear to be referring to the whole row object in 'str(col)', and then referring separately to the row *value* in 'PBSID.append(col.value)'. It's best to refer to the same object, whichever is more suitable in your case.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I'm unsure what maths operation you are referring to in the first comment below your screenshot. However, your second comment with regards to the "whole row object" is a good lead indeed. I tried printing that to the console and it returns "E193" (so a single cell). I am unsure how to return the full list of IDs as expected...

Comment: Hi there, no worries. The operation I'm referring to is 256 minus 23690, which is -23434. What I'm saying is that I think Python is interpreting '256-23690' as a subtraction operation on two numbers, not as a single string. So by the time you try the regular expression, it's searching on the number '-23434'  (with no matches), not on the string '256-23690' (for which there would be a match).